# why this way "this.foo = new (function () {..})();" vs. "this.foo = function (){...};"

Tags: javascript

Is there any difference in the two definitions and assignments of functions?

```
this.foo = new (function () {..})();
```

vs.

```
this.foo = function (){...};
```

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2274695/new-function-with-lower-case-f-in-javascript and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895635/javascript-singleton-question

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the first example, it's creating a function and executing it, assigning the result to this.foo.  In the second example, it's creating the function and assigning the function itself to this.foo.

Comment: this.foo in the second example, is equivalent to a function pointer correct?

Comment: @KennyCason: You can look at it that way.  It is assigning the function to the variable `foo` in the current context.  However, writing `function foo() {....}` will do *exactly* the same thing.

Comment: @james not quite exactly, `function foo()` will asign it at the top of scope, `this.foo = function()` assigns it right there

Answer (score 3):

The main difference is calling the function with a "new" and assigning the anonymous function to a variable

ECMA 262 15.3.2:
When Function is called as part of a new expression, it is a constructor: it initialises the newly created object.

So `this.foo = new (function () {..})();` creates a new object and assigns it to `this.foo`

and

`this.foo = function (){...};` defines an anonymous function and assigns it to this.foo

also another way is `this.foo = (function () {..})();` (without the "new") will call the function and assign its return value to `this.foo`

In your case if you alert:

```
var foo = new (function () {})();
var bar = function() {};
var baz = (function () {return "boo";})(); // without the "new"

alert(foo); // will alert [object Object], the newly created object
alert(bar); // will alert function) {}, the function itself
alert(baz); // will alert "boo", the functions return value
```

Answer (score -2):

Your first example is plain wrong, have you actually tried it? If you want to use `new` and  the `Function` constructor it works like this:

```
foo = new Function("function body");
```

(This is the worst possible way of defining a function)

**Example 2 is the way to go.**

Comment: The anonymous function in the first example could return a function, which is then used with the `new` operator. Perhaps the anonymous function is some sort of object factory?

Comment: Actually @Ryan it won't do that unless you wrap the right side of that expression (i.e., the whole function call) in another layer of parens. The "new" operator binds at least as tightly as (), so it's like `(new (function() { ... })) ()` as currently written.

Comment: `new function() { ... }` is fine to do.  It doesn't do the same thing as `new Function()`.  It does the same thing as `new MyConstructor()`, which is perfectly valid.

Comment: @Pointy - you're right that I need another layer of parentheses, but I think it would be more like `foo = new (function() {...}())();` Either way, not a very easy syntax to use, and it defeats the purpose of an object factory anyway.